# Python: Use the "value" of a class instance as the value of a specified class instance attribute

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python and have a question relating to accessing class instance attributes.

**Consider the example below**

```
import numpy as np

class TwoDimensionalArray:
    def __init__(self, input_array):
        self.dimension_one_size = input_array.shape[0]
        self.dimension_two_size = input_array.shape[1]
        self.value = my_array

# Create an instance of the class TwoDimensionalArray.
numpy_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
example_two_dimensional_array = TwoDimensionalArray(numpy_array)
```

My actual code is a bit more complex than this example; the motivation for requiring this functionality is that I do not want to write `numpy_array.shape[0]` or `numpy_array.shape[1]` throughout my code base, but rather the dimensions must have names that are suitable for the business logic at hand.

Is it at all possible to modify the class `TwoDimensionalArray` in some way such that you get the input array without having to write `a_different_array = example_two_dimensional_array.value` (i.e. **.** to access the attribute `value`) but rather use the simplification `a_different_array = example_two_dimensional_array` i.e. `a_different_array` will then be equal to `np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` i.e. `type(a_different_array) = type(numpy_array) = numpy.ndarray` as opposed to `type(a_different_array) = TwoDimensionalArray`?

Comment: `a_different_array is example_two_dimensional_array` but `type(a_different_array) != type(example_two_dimensional_array)`, do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html#simple-example-adding-an-extra-attribute-to-ndarray.

**It seems the correct way to implement this is as follows**

```
class TwoDimensionalArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.dimension_one_size = input_array.shape[0]
        obj.dimension_two_size = input_array.shape[1]
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.dimension_one_size = getattr(obj, 'dimension_one_size', None)
        self.dimension_two_size = getattr(obj, 'dimension_two_size', None)        
        
numpy_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
example_two_dimensional_array = TwoDimensionalArray(numpy_array)
```

We now have two additional attributes added to `np.ndarray`: `example_two_dimensional_array.dimension_one_size = 2` and `example_two_dimensional_array.dimension_two_size = 3`.